# Are there situations in which Blender Render is the better choice?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

There are two Render Engines in Blender, Blender Render was the first one, now Blender is enhanced by Cycles.

In all tutorials I have seen so far Cycles was the default choice. Only in one recent tutorial, it was about how to create a 80s style laser grid, the tutor has used Blender Render.

Is Cycles in each situation superior to Blender Render, or are there situations were choosing Blender Render makes more sense?

Comment: comparatives like better, worse, superior are going to yield opinions that are only those of their authors but not necessarily yours... having said that there are differences between the two and is up to you to use each render engine to suit your needs. Some suggested links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal and 
 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20825/how-does-blender-internal-work/20829#20829 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261/what-are-the-differences-between-lamps-in-cycles-and-blender-internal

Comment: also : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19012/which-engine-in-blender-should-i-start-with

Answer (score 2):

Some external game engines do not make use of the cycles rendering engine, and for content made for use with games running these engines, the internal Blender engine is a better choice. *Minecraft* is an example of one such game.

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to use Blender Render to create programmatic screenshots of objects via the Blender Python API. I see Cycles Render as a full-fledged animator, but I use Blender Render as a quick rendering utility.