# Why do the controls for materials look different?

Tags: materials, interface

The first image, the material properties shows in one way.
  [image]

On the second image, the material properties, is displayed in a different way
[image]

Why is it different?

could you tell me why this happens to me? thank you, regards

Comment: see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14131/bsdf-options-not-availble-in-texture and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6831/shader-nodes-are-missing

Comment: Read: [how is cycle different from blender internal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two different render engines, in the first image you are using cycles, in the second blender internal.

[image]

more info: 
[Which engine in Blender should i start with?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19012/which-engine-in-blender-should-i-start-with?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[How is Cycles different from Blender Internal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your information, exactly it looked like this for having the engine in internal, greetings.